# Is there a way to customize where vs code looks for local environments?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure vs code to automatically find workspace-local virtual environments other than in ./venv or ./.venv (where . = ${workspaceFolder})?

I sometimes find it necessary to switch between python versions when debugging.  I create virtual environments at paths like ./venv/3.11 (for Python 3.11-series releases).  However, with paths like that, I need to manually point vs code at them to use them.

I've tried setting python.venvFolders, like this:

```
"python.venvFolders": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/3.11",
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/3.10",
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/3.9"
]
```

but I think that variable is implicitly rooted at a user's home directory (and, in any case, doesn't work).